# Scala annotation inheritance from trait

Tags: scala, annotations, swagger

I'm using `Swagger` for generating documentation. This library during parsing classes uses `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation.

I have a lot of entities extended by `Entity` `trait`

```
case class Device extends Entity
```

I don't want this entity properties to be added to output JSON. In this case I need to add such annotation:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = Array("net$fwbrasil$activate$entity$BaseEntity$$_baseVar", "_varsMap",
  "net$fwbrasil$activate$entity$BaseEntity$$_vars", "version", "net$fwbrasil$activate$entity$BaseEntity$$persistedflag",
  "net$fwbrasil$activate$entity$BaseEntity$$initialized", "net$fwbrasil$activate$entity$BaseEntity$$initializing",
  "lastVersionValidation", "net$fwbrasil$activate$entity$EntityListeners$$listeners", "net$fwbrasil$activate$entity$EntityValidation$$_invariants",
  "net$fwbrasil$activate$entity$EntityValidation$$_listener"))
```

I don't want to copy it in every entity, how can I create some abstraction for this annotation to use it in every entity class.

I checked in sources of `Swagger`, and it is using `getAnnotation` method, so is it possible to group this annotation for example using traits, or in some other way?

Comment: What version of swagger are you using?  And are you including the swagger-scala-module?

Comment: I'm using swagger-play2 version 1.3.12